# Yii 1.1 Message files generation Unicode

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have a web app based in yii 1.1 and we are making it multilingual. I generate the translation files through the command:

```
php yiic message messages/config.php
```

The files are being generate with all Yii::t() defined, the problem is in the content, it is generating the content without accents, it's like is not taking the UTF-8 unicode. I guess is a problem with unicode, maybe you guys now the solution.

Thank you in an advance,

See you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by my own, what I made is create a function using this to each string of the array and that's it:

```
html_entity_decode(htmlentities(utf8_decode($key)))
```